# Magnitude of Axis vectors in question

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces

I have a question on my revision sheet:

> Write the vector, **v**=-2 **i** + 4 **j** , in polar form.

is it safe to assume axis vectors i and j have a magnitude of 1?

Answer (score 2):

If $v=x\bf{i}+y\bf{j}\in\mathbb R^2$ then $\arctan(\theta)=\frac{-y}{x}$ and of course $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. So $v(x,y)$ can be written as $v(r,\theta)$.

Comment: We haven't "crossed paths" simultaneously, for a while! ;-)

Comment: @amWhy: Oh dear. Really? I am so happy hearing that. Take care of yourself. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm so relieved, because it was so easily resolved. But I was fearful, because I felt so horribly, so suddenly. but, "All is good that end's well" ;-)

Comment: @BabakS.: Nice answer + 1!

Answer (score 1):

Normally, $\bf{i}$, $\bf{j}$, and $\bf{k}$ denote orthogonal unit vectors, so their length is 1. But this should actually be clear from your text.

Comment: That is all the information it gives...  I should just state that my magnitude and direction were calculated assuming vectors i and j had a magnitude of one unit?